# Remove su when using terminal in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Is there anyway I can stop terminal from automatically using su. I am using parallels on a mac and this is the default when i open terminal in ubuntu virtual machine:

> parallels@ubuntu:$

instead i want:

> parallels@ubuntu:#

Comment: Did you try typing `exit` in the terminal?

Comment: @ARG that just closes the terminal window

Comment: How about pressing CTRL + D ?